# Putting subfigures side by side using subcaption and caption package

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption, sidebyside

I have the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,caption}
\usepackag{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width = 0.75 \textwidth]{./fig1}
                \subcaption{$\epsilon$-Greedy}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width = 0.75 \textwidth]{./fig2}
                \subcaption{UCB}
            \end{subfigure}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is creating the following picture:

[image]

But I want it to look like following (with subcaptions)

[image]

The second picture was created using `subfigure` package which is obsolete now and isn't allowing to put subcaption properly. Nevertheless, this is the code I used

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
            \centering
            \subfigure{
            \includegraphics[width = 0.45 \textwidth]{./fig1}
                }
            \subfigure{
            \includegraphics[width = 0.45 \textwidth]{./fig2}
            }
        \end{figure}
```

Comment: Add `\hfill` after the first   subfigure of your  code using subcaption :  `\end{subfigure}\hfill\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}`

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: @SimonDispa - You were close: what's needed after the first instance of `\end{subfigure}` is `%`, not `\hfill`.

Comment: Both % and \hfill will work.  The important thing is to not end a line with }, which adds an extra space (for which there is not enough room).  BTW, inside subfigure you can use \caption.  Theoretically, using \subcaption would produce a subsubcaption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest two remedies:

- Keep the widths of the `subfigure` environments unchanged, but insert `%` (comment character) immediately after the first instance of `\end{subfigure}`.
- Reduce the widths of the `subfigure` environments from `0.5\textwidth` to `0.45\textwidth`, insert `\hfill` after the first instance of `\end{subfigure}`, and *increase* the width of the included graphics from `0.75\textwidth` to `1\textwidth`. This approach will also let you get rid of all three `\centering` instructions, greatly reducing code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width = 0.75\textwidth]{./fig1}
                \subcaption{$\epsilon$-Greedy}
            \end{subfigure}%     <-- note the % symbol
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width = 0.75\textwidth]{./fig2}
                \subcaption{UCB}
            \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{./fig1}
                \subcaption{$\epsilon$-Greedy}
            \end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- note the \hfill instruction
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{./fig2}
                \subcaption{UCB}
            \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```